# Mysql query to delete duplicates based on part of timestamp

Tags: mysql

I have a webshop which has gotten some duplicate orders because of paypal sending some payment notifications twice or even 3-4-5 times, with random interval between them, ranging from seconds to minutes.

Example from my orders-table:

```
ID     productname    buyer    timestamp
1      apples         john     2014-07-01 19:22:20
2      bananas        john     2014-07-01 19:22:20
3      oranges        mary     2014-07-01 19:22:52
4      apples         john     2014-07-01 19:22:53
5      bananas        john     2014-07-01 19:22:53
6      apples         chris    2014-07-01 19:22:54
```

I want to delete all duplicate rows, and by duplicate i mean that productname, buyer and date of purchase should be equal. (only date, not the time part of the timestamp)

So from the table above, this should be deleted:

```
4      apples         john     2014-07-01 19:22:53
5      bananas        john     2014-07-01 19:22:53
```

Because he bought the same things earlier the same day.

How would you go about doing this?

Comment: Instead of a date/time-based criteria which could easily be any length of time, why not compare the orders themselves?  Any order with the exact same items and quantity to the same customer is a potential duplicate.  Anyway, doesn't Paypal provide your order ID?

Comment: I'd be really annoyed if I were your customer that intentionally made two identical orders on the same day.

Comment: Without any further information, I'm gonna assume it's your side of the application that's messing up, not Paypal. Solving this problem like this seems like a really, really bad idea.

Comment: well, its paypal that send the message multiple times. they have done that maybe 2 or 3 times in the last 4 years ive been running webshops. so its their problem isnt it. i mean i could make measures to fix their error, but its their fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with `EXISTS`

```
DELETE FROM table AS t
WHERE EXISTS(
    SELECT * 
    FROM table 
    WHERE id != t.id 
        AND productname = t.productname 
        AND buyer = t.buyer 
        AND DATE(timestamp) = DATE(t.timestamp))
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here is another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3311903/remove-duplicate-rows-in-mysql). What it really comes down to is making the `id` a unique key field so that you can't insert duplicates in the first place.